# how to check path exist without uppercase and lowercasein python

Tags: string, python-2.7

I have some file but it will be in uppercase or lowercase , I want to remove this check with function os.path.exists()

```
INI_NAME=(cfgname.split("_",1)[1])+".ini"
newpath=newpath+"\\"+cfgname
if os.path.exists(newpath):
   INI_path=self.ECUFolderpath
   INI_path=INI_path+"\\"+INI_NAME
   if(os.path.exists(INI_path)):
       print(exist)
```

In this os.path.exists() function I want to remove uppercase_lower case check

Firstly thanks for help

Comment: I don't see an upper/lower case check in your code; that makes it hard to remove in the first place. Could you explain a bit moer what precisely you want?

Comment: There are also the `str.lower()` and `str.upper()` methods; these should work with path names as well.

Comment: Not sure to understand, could you provide a sample input, and what you want to get? And which os do you use? On windows, paths are not sensible to case...

Comment: As per @olinox14, Windows (what you are using), doesn't care about file case, so it can't be tested for. "MyFile" is the same as "myfile" on Windows.

Comment: nope when I check the path for ABC_DEF.ini and if my file name is ABc_Def then it is not able to find